# iOS UIScrollView fine tuning

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, performance

In Apple's apps I notice the scrolling is perfect. Everything moves nicely and when you stop, it stops. You can have a huge image and move directly to any spot and it stays there.

I'd like to provide the same UE, but for my apps, if the content exceeds the size of the scroll view (as it should - otherwise what's the point in having a scroll view?) the scroll view never stays put, you have to drag to see content on the edges, then it bounces back and hides it again. Very annoying, especially if there is active content like a button there.

I'm not an iOS expert, e.g. I just found out recently about how critical viewWillAppear is w.r.t. UIScrollView. Is there a concise reference somewhere on how to get perfect rock solid scrolling? (i.e. not Apple's Dev docs!)

Thanks for reading,

Yimin

Comment: there are a lot of UIScrollView tutorials on the net, it sounds like your problem is that you haven't sent the contentSize property correctly.

Comment: What is the correct size? Is it exactly the size of the content or should I add a bit all around? I used Wenderlich's tutorial as the base.

Comment: it should be exactly the size of your content + any padding that you need. you don't need to add extra for the bounce areas of the scroll view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the `contentSize` property on the `UIScrollView`?

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 2000);
```

Comment: Yes. I tried setting to the exact size, and adding a lot of padding. I did this in the viewWillAppear event handler.

Comment: Are you sure the scroll view is wired up correctly in Interface Builder? If the scroll view is correctly set, this should work.

Comment: Oh yeah, delegate and instance both. It works, just that it doesn't work as cleanly as Apple's native stuff. Done beating my head trying to make it perfect, I'll submit the app and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has access to internals which we don't so its products tend to perform better. Scrolling in iOS is basically take it or leave it. Have followed the guidelines in the tutorials and they all have flakey scrolling, in particular the edges aren't always visible when zoomed.